# jacobson radical nilpotence, associative algebras.

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, gap

In $Pierce, Associative Algebras$, it is mentioned that the Jacobson radical of a right-artinian associative algebra $A$ is nilpotent, meaning $J(A)^k=0$ for a natural number $k$. However, my professor said that this isn't meant in the sense that $a^k=0$ for all elements $a\in J(A)$, rather that the Jacobson radical is $0$, when written as a linear combination of $k$ elements. What does this mean, and, is there an example for this?

I am now trying to write a code in GAP to calculate the quiver for non-commutative Algebras. However, I am stuck at this point, as I don't know how this linear combination is supposed to look.

Comment: There seems to be a missing assumption for $A$, since the Jacobson radical of a ring is not nilpotent in general (take $A=\mathbb{R}[[x]]$, for example).  Is it possible that Pierce assumes that $A$ is Artinian?

Comment: @Pierre-GuyPlamondon Oh, sorry. Indeed, $A$ is assumed to be right-Artinian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An ideal $I$ is said to be a **nilpotent ideal** if the ideal product $I^k=\{0\}$ for some natural number $k$.

Now in general, the ideal product $I^k$ would consist of all finite sums of products of $k$ elements in $I$. In other words, each element looks like $\sum_{j=1}^n \prod_{m=1}^k i_{jm}$ where all $i_{jm}\in I$ and $n$ can be any natural number (but $k$ is the one we specified.)

But in our case, if $I^k=\{0\}$, any product of $k$ elements of $I$ is zero, and hence any finite sum of them is zero too. So, this is equivalent to *every product of length $k$ of elements of $I$ being $0$*.  So, you can see that this is strictly stronger than every element simply being nilpotent.

An ideal for which every element is nilpotent is called a **nil ideal**.  The Jacobson radical also need not be nil, either. Here are some rings whose [Jacobson radicals aren't nil](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=1&L=22) and here are some whose [Jacobson radical isn't nilpotent, but is nil](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=1&H=22&L=21).  There are even rings whose [Jacobson radicals are nilpotent but are not Artinian](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=1&H=21&L=63l).

> the Jacobson radical is $\{0\}$, when written as a linear combination of $k$ elements. What does this mean, and, is there an example for this?

This seems to be what I'm describing above, although perhaps a little garbled. The things that are being combined *come from $J(R)$* and we are not really talking about linear combinations, but *sums of products*.

I think an easy to understand example would be something like $k[x,y]/(x,y)^2$. The Jacobson radical is easily seen to be $(x,y)$, and not only are $x^2=y^2=0$, but also $xy=0$.

Comment: So, if I have determined the generators of the Jacobson radical, I can determine $J(A)^2$ by taking the products of each pair of generators?

Comment: @UnexpectedExpectation if you have a generating set for $J(R)$, the products will be of the form $g_irg_js$, after you distribute.  It doesn’t really simplify anything. The products of pairs of generators is only a small subset of those...